# How to get value of node list in xml dom parser?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnodelist

I have one XML which look like this ::

```
<Channels>
       <Channel Id="511" Title="Test" ChannelDescription="This is Test Channel./>
</Channels>
```

I am successfully parse this kind of XML.My Problem is that when i fired the webservice and if there is no authentication from the server then the webservice response like this::

```
<AuthenticationError>An Active Session Already Exists For This User.</AuthenticationError>
```

So how can i check that root node is "Authentication Error" or "Notes". And if i get the Authentication Error tag then how can i get its node value which is "An Active Session Already Exists For This User."??

Code for XML Parsing is this::

```
NodeList node =null;
node= (NodeList)result.getElementsByTagName("Channels");


for(int j=0;j<node.getLength();j++)
{                             
Node aNode=node.item(j);  
Element fstElmnt = (Element) aNode;

NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Channel");
int check=websiteList.getLength();

for(int k=0;k<check;k++)
{
    DatabaseConstant myChannels = new DatabaseConstant();
    Node checkNode=websiteList.item(k);

    Element websiteElement = (Element) checkNode;                                                                               
    myChannels.id=websiteElement.getAttribute("Id");
    myChannels.title=websiteElement.getAttribute("Title");

    channel .add(myChannels);
    }
}
}
```

I hope my question is clear... Please provide the solution asap. Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getDocumentElement()` to get root `Element`, then use `getTagName()` to get tag name.

Example:

```
    Element root = result.getDocumentElement();
    String name = root.getTagName();

    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("AuthenticationError") )
    {
        String value = myDocument.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
        System.out.println("Error:" + value);
    }
    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Notes") )
    {
       NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("Channels");

       for(int i = 0 ; i < nodes.getLength() ; i ++)
       {
           //-----do something with channels nodes--
       }
    }
```