# Cant Parse XML in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, format

I am new to XML parsing. I will get an XML string as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="746384773" name="name" gender="F" yob="1994" co="Father's name" house="6-123123" street="street name" vtc="Kakumanu" po="Kakumanu" dist="Goodallor" state="Andhra Pradesh" pc="123456"/>
```

I need to parse this. From what I saw googling. XML format is different from what I have here which is given below.
XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<records>
   <employee>
      <name>Sairamkrishna</name>
      <surname>Mammahe</surname>
      <salary>50000</salary>
   </employee>

   <employee>
      <name>Gopal </name>
      <surname>Varma</surname>
      <salary>60000</salary>
   </employee>

   <employee>
      <name>Raja</name>
      <surname>Hr</surname>
      <salary>70000</salary>
   </employee>

</records>
```

And I can't implement usual codes available for parsing an XML String. I don't know what is wrong. Is this normal XML format. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
My parsing code is as shown below:

```
// parsing QR XML
  private String getAadharNumber(String xml)
      throws XmlPullParserException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String value = null;
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stream);

    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
    element.normalize();

    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("PrintLetterBarcodeData");
    Node node = nodes.item(0);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element elements = (Element) node;
      value = elements.getAttribute("uid");
      return value;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

And I am getting this **error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                             Process: in.co.federalbank.mpassbook, PID: 15662
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=114910, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {in.co.federalbank.mpassbook/in.co.federalbank.mpassbook.CreateEKYCAccountActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'short org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeType()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3779)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3822)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1429)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'short org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeType()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at in.co.fragment.registration.ekyc.GetAadharDetailsFragment.getAadharNumber(GetAadharDetailsFragment.java:137)
                                                                                 at in.co.fragment.registration.ekyc.GetAadharDetailsFragment.onResult(GetAadharDetailsFragment.java:110)
                                                                                 at in.co.fragment.registration.ScannerFragment.onActivityResult(ScannerFragment.java:150)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:153)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6490)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3775)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3822) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1429) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you share the parsing code.... XML is valid...

Comment: Both of the code snippets you posted are valid XML. Yours has data stored as attributes, the other has data stored in nested tags. It would be more helpful if you posted a snippet of your parsing code and we could help you determine what is wrong.

Comment: @Nabeel K check this link it may helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119356/how-to-get-value-of-node-list-in-xml-dom-parser

Comment: @Nabeel check this liink for xml parsing :https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Comment: @Piyush thanks. let me try those examples.

Comment: @Manoj thanks. let me try those examples.

Comment: @Karakuri Thanks man.

Comment: @MahbubMukul I have updated my question

Comment: @Karakuri can you please help

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks everyone for your time. I got the solution. I changed my code as shown below:

```
 private String getAadharNumber(String xml)
      throws XmlPullParserException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String value = null;
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
    myparser.nextTag();
    String name = myparser.getName();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("PrintLetterBarcodeData")) {
      value = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "uid");
      return value;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing xml in android is very easy. You just need to call your API via `Asynctask`. I am providing here only function that will parse your xml response.
Just change your code according to your requirement in the given function.

```
// This function will parse the output (XML) from the webservice.
private void parseXml(XmlPullParser myParser)
{
    try {
        int event;
        String text = null;
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            String name = myParser.getName();
            switch(event)
            {
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("records")){
                        //if state is not default state
                        if( !(text.equalsIgnoreCase("37"))) {
                            emp_record.add(text);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")){
                        //if state is not default state
                        if(!(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Default_State"))) {
                            emp_info.add(text);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }// end of switch

            event = myParser.next();
        }
    } 
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}// end of parseXml
```

This is just a demo function. Try it yourself.

P.S.:- Before parsing, please do read about `XmlPullParser` class. And also I have used `ksoap2` library to achieve this.

Thanks. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at developer android page ?
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: Answers that are just links are generally discouraged. These are better left as comments on the original post.